# SWT FileDialog is missing the navigation bar on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a small eclipse RCP application.

I have noticed that on windows 10 `FileDialog` doesn't have the path part available.

I have tried different combinations of `Style` flags during the initialization of the dialog but it didn't work.

It is worth mentioning that everything is alright on windows 7.

**No navigation bar on windows 10:**
[image: SWT FileDialog with no navigation bar]

**Expected:**
[image: Expected file dialog with navigation bar]

Further investigation of that issue I got to the following:

The dialog appears correctly with the navigation bar if I start it out of the `WorkbenchAdvisor`.

The code basically is like this:

```
@Override 
public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {       
    try {
        int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, new WorkbenchAdvisor() {

            @Override
            public void postStartup() {
                // THIS MAKES THE DIALOG APPEAR WITHOUT NAVIGATION BAR
                Display display = new Display();
                Shell shell = new Shell(display);
                FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog (shell, SWT.OPEN | SWT.MULTI);
                dialog.open();
                shell.close();
                while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
                    if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) {
                        display.sleep ();
                    }
                }
            }

        });
        if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART) {
            return IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;
        }
        return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
    } finally {
        Display.getDefault().dispose();
    }
    return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
}
```

I need to be able to start the `FileDialog` correctly after starting my workbench.

If I do the following the dialog appears correctly with the navigation bar but this is not the desired:

```
@Override 
public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {
    // THIS MAKES THE DIALOG APPEAR WITH THE NAVIGATION BAR CORRECTLY
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog (shell, SWT.OPEN | SWT.MULTI);
    dialog.open();
    shell.close();
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) {
            display.sleep ();
        }
    }
    Display.getDefault().dispose();
    return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
}
```

I still can't figure out how to fix this or what is really happening.

Another piece of info is that if I start my RCP from eclipse using a launch configuration it works just fine, the file dialog appears with the navigation bar even if I start it inside the `WorkbenchAdvisor`.

Comment: Just guessing:  did you try using `Display.getDefault()` instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Yes, I have tried `Display.getDefault()` and there was no difference and I have checked its body and found that it basically falls back to `new Display()` if no display was initialized before so it is kinda the same.I also tried `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay();` when I am executing from within the `WorkbenchAdvisor` `postStartup` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension.  You declare it on your plugin.xml.

This extension requires you to provide a class that implements the `IStartup` interface.  This class' `earlyStartup` method runs **after** `WorkbenchAdvisor.postStartup`.

Maybe by this time the navigation bar appears.

Comment: That worked as well as using `IPlatformRunnable` instead of `IApplication`.